# non-JS module files deprecated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6sXu.png)
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1466], locale en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

• No issues found!

Comment: Delete your launch.json file

Comment: can you share  launch.json file ?